# Show Input Parameter in jasper report?

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports

In my jasper report,I have filter input parameter called first name, last name. Using ireport, how do I show those parameter on my report if the end user enters first name or last name.

On my report, I want to show following using parameters.

Filter by: Firstname -John
           Lastname - Paul

IF None of those parameters is entered, none will be shown.

I hope you guys can help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

One way i had developed this feature, was by reading the parameters specified in the .jasper file (the compiled report). The code for doing so is:

```
        JasperReport template = null;

    try {
        template = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(fs);
        _logger.fine(putUsernameInsideLogger()+"JasperReport file " + template);

    } catch (JRException e) {
        _logger.severe(putUsernameInsideLogger()+"Error during object loading (.jasper file loading) inside insert() method - ReportBean ",e);
    }


    JRParameter[] params = template.getParameters();

    int counter = 1;
            for(JRParameter param : params) {
                System.out.println("PARAMETER nr "+counter++);
              if(!param.isSystemDefined() && param.isForPrompting()){
                  System.out.println("Name: "+param.getName()+ " ,\\nDesc: "+param.getDescription()+" ,\\nDefaultValueExpr: "+param.getDefaultValueExpression()+" ,\\nNestedTypeName: "+param.getNestedTypeName()+ " ,\\nValueClassName: "+param.getValueClassName()+" , \\nNestedType: "+param.getNestedType());

                  if (param.getValueClassName().equalsIgnoreCase("java.lang.String")){
                  //expose a ui component bind }
                  if (param.getValueClassName().equalsIgnoreCase("java.util.Date")){
                   //same as above}     
                  if (param.getValueClassName().equalsIgnoreCase("java.lang.Integer")){
                   //my example
                  RichInputNumberSpinbox ui = new RichInputNumberSpinbox();
                                  ui.setId("rit"+counter);
                                  ui.setLabel(param.getName());
                                  reportFieldsGroupLayout.getChildren().add(ui);}
              }

            }
```

By this, you would be able to get the parameters specified in the report and create your UI components exposed to the user-interface. After that, remember to read the values inserted to those component during report generation time and insert them to a `Map` and pass it to the exporter:

```
Map parameters = new HashMap();
        parameters.put("title", uiComponent.getValue()); //get the value from your ui component
        JasperPrint print = null;
            print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(template, parameters, conn);
```

Answer (score -1):

To show the parameters value in reports just drag a "Text Filed" and just assign the parameter.

If you want to show by default "All" without selecting any parameter, then you can use this condition.

```
     $P{p_firstname} == null? " All " :
   (
     $P{p_firstname}.isEmpty() ? " All ":
     $P{p_firstname}
   )
```